# Node.js with mongo - Rendering "object" instead the data inside the template?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Check my code...

```
var swig = require('swig');
var config = require('../config.json');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var ObjectId = mongojs.ObjectId;
var db = require('mongojs').connect(config.mongoDB, config.mongoDBcollections);
var roles;


db.lists.find({type:'roles'}).toArray(function(err, item) {
    roles = item[0].data;
    console.log(roles);
});

var sharetpl = swig.compileFile(__dirname +'/../html/register.html');
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var output = sharetpl({
    'title': 'Roles Itself',
    'roles' : [roles]
});
res.send(output);
```

};

this is the console.log output...

```
[ { name: 'Web Developer', code: 'wdv' },
  { name: 'Web Designer', code: 'wds' },
  { name: 'System Archtect', code: 'sar' } ]
```

It's all okay, so far...but the html...

server side: <|-- {{roles}} -->

client html : 
<|-- [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] -->

So, basically I'm stucked on it...It's rendering "[object Object]" on the client side instead the data itself :( pretty frustrated. Any clue ? ty !

Comment: Have you tried `{{roles.name}}`?

Comment: what templating language you use for your HTML ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roles` is an array of Objects, so you need to refer to specific fields of each individual object in array.

if you are using `Mustache` the syntax will be as follows:

```
{{#roles}}
  {{name}}, {{code}}
{{/roles}}
```